# How to generate gradient from stripes?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, software-recommendation, gradient

I have rectangles one below another making list of stripes, similar to this:

[image: rainbow]

Now I just want to generate a gradient from this pattern. It should be such that colours mix with the adjacent colours a bit so that it will be a smooth transition between the colours.

I'm looking for some standard solution by which I can generate the gradient for any choice of colour in any order.

How to do it in Photoshop? If you could suggest any tool/website for the same, that would be helpful too.

Comment: Would a large vertical motion blur work?

Comment: Suggesting another tool in case: In Illustrator, you can do this by drawing what you have there, selecting everything and using the blend tool. This will also accomodate curves if you want to use different shapes for each color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comment above, applying ‘Gaussian Blur’ on your objects would give the merging effect but it will not give a smooth gradient effect.
Here is a result for both.
[image]

Now on the Left side, the object is blurred by using ‘Gaussian Blur’ and it is seen that the lines don’t merge nicely also if you will try to blur the object more than this, the object and colors will disappear.

Now, for the result shown on the right side using “Gradient effect” -  you can generate it using gradient tool. Here are the steps you should follow.

1) Draw the shape on which you want to apply your gradient.

2) Select the shape layer from the ‘Layer’ panel.

3)Select the ‘Gradient tool’ from the ‘Tool’ panel or press shift + g till the tool is activated.

4) You can select one of the given preset and choose your colors.

5) You can adjust the nodes to let the colors merge properly and also you can adjust the angle for the gradient for a better result.

[image]

Follow these steps and you will be able to achieve any gradient effect over any shapes you want.

Answer (score 1):

1. Select your rectangles and `Convert to Smart Object`.
2. Apply `Filter` > `Blur` > `Gaussian Blur`, adjust until you're satisfied.

You can edit your Smart Object to change the order of the rectangles if you want a different color order. Perhaps apply a vector mask to the Smart Object to ensure the outer edges don't get blurred, if you want sharp a outer rectangle with a soft gradient inside.